# Accessing data across databases with different authentication type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure in `DB1` which can be logged in via Windows authentication. I need to save the output of the `SELECT` in the stored procedure to go into a table present in database `DB2`, which uses SQL authentication type.

How can I access the table in `DB2` inside my stored procedure in `DB1`?

Is there any way I can grant access to `DB2` via `DB1`?

Comment: Are these databases on different SQL servers or the same SQL Server?

Comment: They are present on the same server but have different authentication type.

Comment: authentication type is defined at the server level, not the database level. You can actually reference a table in DB2 from DB1 like this: `SELECT * FROM DB2.<schema>.<table>`, i.e. `SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.TABLE`. Try this and get back with any errors.

Comment: The authentication is based on server level. There is an exception occurring - permission not granted.

Comment: Are you allowed to give the login which is accessing DB1, access to DB2? It's as simple as ticking access. See the picture at the top of this page: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2038/understanding-how-a-user-gets-database-access-in-sql-server/ You double click your server login, and tick access to DB2.